# Generate pages from _posts in subfolder in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a project where I have posts on main page of the blog and I would love to have another posts folder inside subfolder(s).

I am talking about this structure:

```
_posts
_posts/2020-04-04-Testmain.md
subpage/_posts
subpage/_posts/2020-04-04-Testsub.md
subpage/index.html
index.html
```

I can access posts from subpage by using `{% for post in site.categories.subpage %}` inside `subpage/index.html` but I can't find a way how to force jekyll to also generate posts in the subpage folder so I can access it at page `http://127.0.0.1:4000/subpage/testsub`

Is it even possible? Or is it better to follow this structure?

```
_posts
_posts/2020-04-04-Testmain.md
_posts/subpage
_posts/subpage/2020-04-04-Testsub.md
```

If so, is there some setting required to make the post at `http://127.0.0.1:4000/subpage/testsub` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

In `_config.yml` you can use `permalink: /:categories/:title`

And with following file hierarchy:

```
_posts
_posts/2020-04-04-Testmain.md
subpage/_posts
subpage/_posts/2020-04-04-Testsub.md
subpage/index.html
index.html
```

You will get these websites:

```
http://127.0.0.1:4000/
http://127.0.0.1:4000/subpage/
http://127.0.0.1:4000/subpage/testsub
```

And you can still access all posts from selected subfolder with `{% for post in site.categories.subpage %}`